# Different result for zxing QRscanner

Tags: android, android-studio, qr-code, zxing

I have three different EditText and three different Qr button. Every button setText to each EditText. Can anyone help me about it.

Scanqr function

```
public void scanQRCode(View view, String from) {
        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
        integrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
        integrator.setCameraId(0);
        integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
        integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
        integrator.addExtra("from", from);
        integrator.initiateScan();
    }
```

Activity Result

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        final IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null) {
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //do any.


            }
        } else {
            // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

can i put something like intent putextra to check which button i click?
Hope someone can help please. Thx so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int clickedButton = 0;

findViewById(R.id.your_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickedButton = 1;
        }
    });

findViewById(R.id.your_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickedButton = 2;
        }
    });

findViewById(R.id.your_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickedButton = 3;
        }
    });
```

in onActivityResult check `if(clickedButton == 1)` set the text to particular edittext

Comment: I will try on it. Hope its success.

Comment: Its work for my situation. So simple yet cant find out. thank you

Comment: it's ok.. Enjoy :)